# Remove Android input orange border in a NON APP website

Tags: android, input, border, outline

I'm working on a version of the main website for mobile devices. I'm trying to remove the orange border from input text fields...

I tried so far this: `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);`, `outline:none;` and `border:0px` !important..  and it just works for Chrome desktop not Android.

Note that I'm NOT working on an App so I wouldn't be able to use the `EditView` thingy..

Will appreciate any answer even if it is not possible..

Comment: Any luck with this? If so can you share your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can't. The only hack is to make the objects something other than href-links or input buttons. But nothing you do in CSS will override this. It's annoying.

For everything else, use this:

> -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);

Answer (score 0):

This CSS works for me:

```
*:focus  
{  
    outline: none;  
}
```